# Input property not being updated when using callback function

Tags: angular, firebase, callback, nativescript

I need to update a property in a child component when a push notification is received from firebase. Firebase is configured correctly and I have the property configured as an input properly. The value is updated in the child successfully when I manually trigger the change using a button. However, when the value is changed using a callback the value will be updated but the child is not notified of the change.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private orders_updated:boolean = false;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //firebase.init() removed for space
        firebase.addOnMessageReceivedCallback((data) => {
            this.interpret_message(data);
        });
    }

    private clicked() {
        this.orders_updated = !this.orders_updated;
        console.log(this.orders_updated)
    }

    private interpret_message(message:any) {
        if (message.body == "A new order was submitted") {
            this.clicked();
        }
    }
}
```

```js
export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit {
    private _update:boolean;

    @Input() set update(value: boolean){
        this._update = value;
        console.log("Value updated")
    }
}
```

When the clicked function is called manually I receive an update that the value in TransactionComponent was updated. However, when clicked is called as the result of a callback I do not receive "Value updated" message. I believe that by using an arrow function I am not running into a scope issue.

Comment: have you tried using ngOnChanges, as OnChanges hook is used to check when input changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not guaranteed to be operating in the same `NgZone` when responding through an `async` channel like firebase.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    private orders_updated:boolean = false;

    constructor(private zone: NgZone) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        //firebase.init() removed for space
        firebase.addOnMessageReceivedCallback((data) => {
            this.interpret_message(data);
        });
    }

    private clicked() {
        this.zone.run(() => {
          this.orders_updated = !this.orders_updated;
          console.log(this.orders_updated)
        });
    }

    private interpret_message(message:any) {
        if (message.body == "A new order was submitted") {
            this.clicked();
        }
    }
}
```